# Larave SASS importing methods

Tags: css, laravel, sass

i have a `laravel` project where i import various `CSS` and `sass` package. there are few import methods which are totally different which one is the best practice for import it. detailed information would be appreciated

- `@import '~bootstrap/sass/bootstrap';` what does `~` syntax do?
- `@import 'variables';`
- `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');`

can anyone explain between these different?
`@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";`

what is the purpose of `~` and `@` symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy your css file to `/resources/assets/css/yourfile.css`

add `@import "../css/yourfile.css";` to the bottom of `/resources/assets/sass/app.scss`

If you haven't already installed the node dependencies, run `npm install run npm run dev`

Your custom css is now included in the `/public/css/app.css` file.

Comment: i wanted to know the explanation. what is the different between those three methods and how it works